# Is it possible to upgrade the version of YUI inside Liferay?

Tags: yui, liferay-6

I am using Liferay 6.1.1GA2, which includes YUI 3.4.0. As of this posting, the YUI library is currently up to version 3.8.0.

Is there a way to upgrade this library within Liferay so that I won't have to include the newer version inside each portlet I deploy? I can see including the current version on top of the Liferay version [leading to problems](https://www.liferay.com/forums/-/message_boards/message/11071590/maximized) very quickly.

Comment: i dont think you can just "replace" YUI, i think you will run into trouble 100%
guess you will have to wait for liferay to update their dependencies

Comment: i have also found [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7726261/yui-version-conflict-issue-in-portlet) maybe it can help you but after a quick look i dont think this is good news